# Binding data through PHP to Android using JSON

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am developing an android application using PHP and mysql as external database. Now in my activity page whole JSON data are there but not bind in listview. I tried a lot and search on google as well.

My `activity.java` is below:

```
private void getdatalatlog(double latitude, double longitude) {
    String link = "http://192.168.0.104/PHP/webservice/comments.php?latitude='"+latitude+"'&longitude='"+longitude+"'";
    aq.progress(R.id.progressBar1).ajax(link, JSONObject.class, this,"jsonCallback");
}

public void jsonCallback(String link, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) throws JSONException {                
    mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(link);        
    mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String content = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);            
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, content);
            map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
            mCommentList.add(map);              
        }
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
            R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE,TAG_USERNAME ,TAG_MESSAGE
                    }, new int[] { R.id.shop_name,R.id.address,R.id.distance
                     });

    setListAdapter(adapter);        
    ListView lv = getListView();    
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
```

My `getdatalatlong()` method is called in `onCreate()` method. And in `jsonCallback()` method's `json object`, I got all data of my database.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are getting the JSON Object from the server.

if you got means do this. Store that JSON Result in an string(usually i call it JSONString).

For example :

```
{
    "username":"Vignesh";
    "title" : "Check My Site";
    "content" : "vickytechy.hol.es"
}
```

Then use this to get the values by the index

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);//JSONString is the JSON result;
Name = jsonObject.optString("username");//Name = Vignesh
Title = jsonObject.optString("title");//Title = Check My Site
Content = jsonObject.optString("content");//Content = vickytechy.hol.es
```